# Regex error:nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried a regular expression to validate a number with or without decimal with maximum 2 places.
I did this

```
var patt=  /(^\d+[.]?\d{1,2}+$)/g;
```

It is working in RegExr application.

but in chrome there is an error

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^\d+[.]?\d{1,2}+$)/: Nothing to repeat
```

what wrong am I doing in this? Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
var patt =  /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/g;
```

What made your regexp incorrect is `+` sign after `{1,2}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `\d{1,2}+`.

`{n,m}` says that the previous character must occur `n` to `m` times.

`+` says that the previous character must occur at least one time.

You can't use both of these together

Answer (score 0):

```
var patt = /^\d+\.?\d{1,2}$/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of the regex is wrong: `\d{1,2}+`

The `+` means it repeat 1 or more times and the `{1,2}` means it repeats 1 or 2 times. So you have 2 repeat things in front of eachother. This won't work.

How to solve this?

- Remove `+` to repeat a digit (0-9) 1 or 2 times
- Remove `{1,2}` to repeat a digit 1 or more times, and as much as posible.